# defining url in helm chart values as a variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have the following yaml file in values.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  url: {{ .Release.Name }}.abc.com
```

but when I lint it with helm it shows the following error

Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected key

if I put "{{ .Release.Name }}.abc.com" it then the .Release.Name is not working. Im new to helm. thank you

Answer (score 0):

helm doesn't support re-rendering like this, you need to use `named template` to make it work.

[Named Template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/)

e.g.

templates/_helpers.tpl

```yaml
...
{{- define "ingressConfig" -}}
ingress:
  enabled: false
  url: {{ .Release.Name }}.abc.com
{{- end -}}
...
```

Use it in other templates like configmap.yaml

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    {{- include "ingressConfig" . | nindent 4 }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    ingress:
      enabled: false
      url: test.abc.com
```